# initialize Issue about Corda's flow test

Tags: testing, blockchain, smartcontracts, corda

I am trying to implement a flow test for my corda app written in java, but when I start to run a sample test to have a start I find this error:

```
Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
....
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker. (This mock maker is not supported on Android.)
Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 25.341-b10
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_341-b10
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 11
OS version         : 10.0
```

I think the mockito plugin should be included in the corda.testing library that I have imported, and my corda environment set up should be fine since I can compile and run my corda app normally, and since I am runing the sample app, it should not be the code's problem. I have googled about it but didn't find anything useful, any suggestion about this will be helpful.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the reference/version of mockito and corda. Did you try using a different version? An older or a newer one?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, I am currently using corda 4.9 and I have tried 4.8 and 4.7 but not work. Because of the word limit, I post my code's setting information at a question at corda forum here: https://developer.r3.com/forums/topic/having-trouble-to-run-flow-test/#post-10211